# Efficient principal pivots

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-programming

It was suggested I should try posting this question here from [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135447/efficient-principal-pivots)

**Background**

I'm working on a numerical linear algebra package in C#.  I'm trying to implement a variety of "principal pivoting" methods to solve optimization problems (specifically linear complementarity problems, but I think similar schemes are used in linear and quadratic programming).  These methods require the ability to multiply a column vector against the "principal pivotal transform" of a matrix.

The principal pivot transform (PPT) of a matrix $M$ is defined as:

$$PM^'P^T = \left (\begin{array}{cc} M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1} &\ -M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1} M_{\alpha\beta} \\ M_{\beta\alpha}M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1} &\ M_{\beta\beta} - M_{\beta\alpha} M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1}M_{\alpha\beta} \end{array} \right )$$

Where $\alpha$ is the set of pivoted row/column indices, and $\beta$ is the set of unpivoted row/column indices.  $P$ is a permutation matrix that keeps the pivoted and unpivoted rows/columns together to make the block matrix form above cleaner.  $M_{\alpha\beta}$ is a submatrix of $M$ with the rows in $\alpha$ and the columns in $\beta$, and the other submatrices of $M$ are defined similarly.  Also, $M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1} = (M_{\alpha\alpha})^{-1}$ and not $(M^{-1})_{\alpha\alpha}$

...

Each iteration of a principal pivot method swaps a single index from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ or vice-verse.  This single pivoting operation can be expressed as a low rank update of the matrix.  Say we're pivoting index $r$ and using $M^'$ to represent the updated matrix:

$$\begin{matrix}
M_{rr}^' & = & & \frac{1}{M_{rr}} & \\ \\ \\
M_{ir}^' & = & & \frac{M_{ir}}{M_{rr}}, & (i \neq r) \\ \\ \\
M_{ri}^' & = & & \frac{-M_{ri}}{M_{rr}}, & (i \neq r) \\ \\ \\
M_{ij}^' & = & M_{ij} - & \frac{M_{ir} * M_{ri}}{M_{rr}}, & (i \neq r, j \neq r)
\end{matrix}
$$

This is what I'm currently doing.  Unfortunately, this is basically calculating $M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1}$ using something like Gaussian elimination.  I have a few test cases where the results are suffering from numerical problems even on on small problems, even using double precision floating point.  To help combat this, if I remove an index from $\alpha$ (that is, if I unpivot an index), I recalculate the matrix from scratch using one pivot at a time with the above scheme.  But this makes the Principal Pivot algorithm I have quite slow.

**Question**

I know there are reasonable ways to calculate the product $M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1} z$ for some column vector $z$ without calculating $M_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1}$ directly (such as LU decomposition or QR decomposition).  I could calculate this decomposition fresh every iteration from the current pivot set ($\alpha$), and probably get a pretty robust method.  But then each iteration of the pivoting algorithm would take $O(n^3)$; that's too slow.  I could do a low rank update of the LU or QR decomposition, but since most of the algorithms pivot a single index at a time, I lose most of the benefit of these decomposition schemes after a few iterations.  I could perform the full decomposition only every few iterations, but then the question becomes how often should I do so?  And it still would be quite slow.

Is there something more clever that can be done?  I think I basically need to find the decomposition of principal submatrices.  Is there any literature on the subject?  Any other ways to approach the problem?

Comment: Is $M$ dense, positive-definite and/or symmetric in the general case?

Comment: In my case it's symmetric and PSD.  It's actually formed from the normal equations of some rank deficient dense matrices.  I know there are some iterative schemes that might work well here, but I wanted to explore pivoting methods.

Comment: If it's SPD, then you can take the Cholesky decomposition, and there is a fair amount of literature on how to stably update the Cholesky decomposition using low-rank factors as you are suggesting.  This is very commonly used in implementations of simplectical solvers, so I would not be surprised if it turns out to be the most efficient for you.

Comment: Ah, that's actually an interesting idea.  I'll look in to it.